# return and auto deduce std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following:

```
auto x = {0}; // auto deduction of std::initializer_list<int>
auto y = []() -> std::initializer_list<int> { return {0}; }(); //explicit
auto z = []() { return {0}; }(); // won't compile
```

why it's not possible to return and auto deduce the type of std::initializer_list?

Comment: Did you try `auto z = []() -> auto { return {0}; }();`?

Comment: Note that you do **not** want it to deduce `initializer_list` anyway, because the values in the list have lifetime of the lambda - they're not extended by a function return. They are destroyed before you could use `y` or `z`. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286450/lifetime-of-a-stdinitializer-list-return-value). The `y` line causes UB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, because the Standard says so, and because a *braced-init-list* is not an expression. Per paragraph 5.1.2/4 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] If
>   a *lambda-expression* does not include a *trailing-return-type*, it is as if the *trailing-return-type* denotes the
>   following type:
>
> — if the *compound-statement* is of the form
>
> `{` *attribute-specifier-seq(opt)* `return` *expression* `; }`
>
> **the type of the returned expression** after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1), array-to-pointer conversion
>   (4.2), and function-to-pointer conversion (4.3);
>
> — otherwise, `void`.

The above makes it clear that the return type will be deduced to be anything else then `void` if and only if the `return` statement is followed by an *expression*, and a *braced-init-list* is not in itself an expression - it does not have a type, and it does not yield a value. It is just a language construct that can be used in the context of initialization.

The above paragraph also provides an example:

> [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> auto x1 = [](int i){ return i; }; // OK: return type is int
> auto x2 = []{ return { 1, 2 }; }; // error: the return type is void (a
>                                   // braced-init-list is not an expression)
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

Finally, if the question is:

"*Why a special rule was introduced for deducing the type of an `auto` variable initialized from a braced-init-list, while a similar rule was **not** introduced for deducing the return type of a lambda when `return` is followed by a braced-init-list?*"

Then the question is not constructive. Also notice, that type deduction for templates does not work with *braced-init-lists* either:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T);

foo({1, 2}); // ERROR! T is NOT deduced to be std::initializer_list<int>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy for the answer. I thought deduction for auto and templates follows the same rules but you're giving a counterexample.

Comment: @a.lasram: They do in most situations, but there are exceptions. Actually, I think the one I pointed out at the end of the answer is the *only* exception - although I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @ Andy Prowl - sorry, same situation as auto: foo({1, 2}) fails but foo<std::initializer_list<int>>({1, 2}) would pass.

Comment: @a.lasram: I understood what you meant ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the accepted answer makes perfect sense, but I would like to add a bit of context from ["Effective Modern C++" by Scott Meyers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491903996):

> C++98/03 had a single set of rules for type deduction: the one for function templates. C++11 modifies that ruleset a bit and adds two more, one for `auto` and one for `decltype`. C++14 then extends the usage contexts in which `auto` and `decltype` may be employed.
>
> [...]
>
> Deducing types for `auto` is, with only one exception, the same as deducing types for templates.
>
> - `auto` type deduction is usually the same as template type deduction, but `auto` type deduction assumes that a braced initializer represents a `std::initializer_list` and template type deduction doesn't.
> - `auto` in a function return type or a lambda parameter implies template type deduction, not `auto` type deduction.
>
> You might wonder why `auto` type deduction has a special rule for braced initializers, but template type deduction does not. I wonder this myself. Alas, I have not been able to find a convincing explanation. But the rule is the rule [...].