# Using Initializer Lists with Variadic Templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, initializer-list, type-deduction

I have the following code:

```
#define RETURNS(...) -> decltype((__VA_ARGS__)) { return (__VA_ARGS__); }

template <typename This, typename... Args>
auto fun(This &&this_, Args&&... args) RETURNS(this_.fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
```

For better or worse, this allows me to use fun(o, args...) and o.f(args...) interchangeably.  The difficulty in using this comes when using an initializer list as an argument.  E.g.

```
fun(obj, {1, 2, 3}); // Where obj.fun eventually takes a std::vector<int>.
```

This fails due to a substitution error, so Clang says.  Note, `obj.fun({1, 2, 3});` works.

As I understand it from other questions, this is because initializer lists don't always play nicely with template argument deduction.

The closest I have to my desired syntax is by making the initializer list more explicit.  To avoid verbosity, I have the following:

```
template <typename T> std::initializer_list<T> il(std::initializer_list<T> &&li) { return li; }

fun(obj, il({1, 2, 3}));
```

Is there a way of getting my desired syntax or closer to it?

---

Clang's error report in my test program is:

```
subst.cpp:16:5: error: no matching function for call to 'fun'
    fun(x, {1, 2, 3});
    ^~~
subst.cpp:6:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with This
      = X &, Args = <>]: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'v'
      was not specified
auto fun(This &&this_, Args&&... args) RETURNS(this_.fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
     ^                                                                              ~
```

Comment: A substitution error? It should be a [deduction failure](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/859f8b2fac7c2cd8). `{1,2,3}` is not an expression, and it has no type that could be deduced.

Comment: @dyp I have added the error report from Clang.  I think we're in violent agreement, although I may be putting the cart before the horse.  Args does not get deduced (`Args = <>`), thus results in a substitution failure.

Comment: That sound like a quite unhelpful error message. Maybe you should report that to the clang developers.

Comment: You can also let `il` take a variable number of arguments, to allow a syntax like `fun(obj, il(1,2,3))`. Alternatively, an ugly `fun<some_type, std::initializer_list<int>>(obj, {1,2,3})` is also possible (but not recommended).

Comment: @dyp I think it would take some concerted templateze to expand `il(a, b, c, ...)` to `std::initializer_list<A>{a, b, c, ...}`.  Sounds like a challenge.

Comment: Hmmm sorry my suggestion doesn't work, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15286450/420683 Returning an `std::initializer_list` does not extend the lifetime of the underlying array; it might even be impossible to correctly return it from a function :(

Comment: @dyp I have filed http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18740 , with a bit of uselessness tacked on due to a sudden bout of error message blindness.

Comment: Of interest: this issue actually turns up on slide 13 of Scott Meyers's talk, "The Last Thing That D Needs" at D-Conf: http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/47947981/theater?utm_content=buffer9a242&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have provided the signature of your member function `fun`. Let's assume that it has the following signature:

```
class YourClassObj
{
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    SomeType fun(Args ...args) {...}
    ...
};
```

Then the following call:

```
fun(obj, {1, 2, 3});
```

with a forwarding function, causes actually a non-deduced context related to failing to deduce type for `{1,2,3}`. As per the Standard:

> 14.8.2.1 Deducing template arguments from a function call [temp.deduct.call]
>
> > Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template parameter type (call it `P`) with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`) as described below. If `P` is a dependent type, removing references and cv-qualifiers from `P` gives `std::initializer_list<P'>` or `P'[N]` for some `P'` and `N` and the argument is a non-empty initializer list (8.5.4), then deduction is performed instead for each element of the initializer list, taking `P'` as a function template parameter type and the initializer element as its argument, and in the `P'[N]` case, if `N` is a non-type template parameter, `N` is deduced from the length of the initializer list. **Otherwise, an initializer list argument causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced context** (14.8.2.5).

Examples from the standard:

> ```
>    template<class T> void f(std::initializer_list<T>);
>    f({1,2,3}); // T deduced to int
>    template<class T> void g(T);
>    g({1,2,3}); // error: no argument deduced for T
> ```

`std::forward` essentially does template type deduction from function call. Scott Meyers describes in his *Effective Modern C++* book this situation as one of the [*perfect forwarding failure cases*](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=rjhIBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=perfect%20forwarding%20failure%20cases&source=bl&ots=Fl2GW6yxsS&sig=hWsluXOfJAq6wKf4UZaZvYLqRRw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWpPOeyv3LAhUGBiwKHT7oAY0Q6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=perfect%20forwarding%20failure%20cases&f=false). As he said in the book, one simple workaround is to use `auto`:

```
auto __il = {1,2,3};
fun(obj, __il);
```

should compile fine, since `auto` deduces `{1,2,3}` to be a `std::initializer_list<int>`. You can read the whole chapter for more detailed explanation.

And by the way, the other approach with a function `il` returning a `std::initializer_list<T>` should also compile, if the original `fun` signature is actually the same as what I assumed (tested with gcc-4.9.1).