# create an std::initializer_list of 1000 ints with default value of 5

Tags: c++

Is it possible to create an `std::initializer_list<int>` of 1000 elements all initialized to value `5`? As far as I know the only way of creating an `std::initializer_list<int>` of 1000 elements all initialized to `5` is `std::initializer_list<int> { 5, 5, 5, ....1000 times };`. I'm looking for a shorter syntax.

Comment: Why should it be `std::initializer_list`? What do you want to initialize with that? Asking, because `std::vector` for example has a constructor suited for this, and `std::array` could be filled using `std::fill`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I need to pass an `std::initializer_list<int>` as argument to a library function

Comment: With the given description my advise is to just use copy/paste and make your initializer list literally. Anything else is going to stress the compiler in needless ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [variadic pack expansions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion) with [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence#Helper_templates) to create an initializer list with an arbitrary number of elements.  Since you can't return a `std::initializer_list` from a function safely (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286450/lifetime-of-a-stdinitializer-list-return-value)), you need to wrap the function call, for example:

```cpp
template<template Fn, std::size_t ...Ns>
decltype(auto) apply_init_list(Fn &&fn, std::index_sequence<Ns...>)
{
    return std::forward<Fn>(fn)({ ((void)Ns, 5)... });
    //                             ^~~~~~  ^ comma operator
    //                             |
    //                             cast to void to avoid unused value compiler warnings
}
```

And use it like

```
// ...
auto value = apply_init_list(&some_library_function, std::make_index_sequence<1000>{});
// ...
```