# What is expected lifetime of std::intializer_list object in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, initializer-list, object-lifetime

Please consider this simplified [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A() "; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A() "; }
};

int main()
{
    auto l = std::initializer_list<A>{A()};
    std::cout << ". ";
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1GWvGfxne

**GCC** prints here

```
A() . ~A()
```

Meaning that `std::initializer_list` is destructed at the end of scope.

**Clang** prints:

```
A() ~A() .
```

Destroying `std::initializer_list` in the line where it is constructed.

Are both compiler behave correctly here or one of them is wrong?

Comment: If you enable verbose warnings, Clang will tell you the problem. See e.g. [on the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/e5GTofe95).

Comment: Thanks, I see. Still the question is why GCC behaves differently.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286450/lifetime-of-a-stdinitializer-list-return-value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's subtle.

A `std::initializer_list` is backed by an underlying array (produced by the compiler). This array is a like a temporary object, and the `std::initializer_list` is a sort of reference type that binds to it. So it will extend the temporary array's lifetime so long as the "reference" exist.

In C++14, we do not have guaranteed copy elision. So what *should* happen is as though `std::initializer_list<A>{A()}` produced a temporary `initializer_list`, bound another *temporary* array to it, and copied the temporary `initializer_list` to `l`.

`std::initializer_list` behaves like a regular reference, as far as lifetime extension is concerned. Only the original reference extends the lifetime, and our original is temporary itself. So the underlying array goes out of existence at the end of the full expression containing the initialization of `l`. Clang is the correct one.

Direct-initialization ...

```
std::initializer_list<A> l {A()};
```

... produces the [same output](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRABmABykr6ADJ5aTAA5ZwAjTGIuTlIAB1QhQnNaO0cXEABWWPjEun9AkKdwyM5o40xTJIYCZmICFOdXTyNMEzM6KpqCPOCwiKijatr6tMyhQa6AnsK%2BkoBKI1QHYmQOKR03AORHLABqTTcbczHiTGYnfexNGQBBK%2Bvjh1Md25vNAHZ9G53v54hZvY%2BOzG6BAKEWBD2B32Nj22m01z%2BsO0%2B10AIAIncfjsAH4I/7vVHA0FoBwQ6HQpG4xE6ZFuVHvDGvN4Yul3O4BCFOZgBP5sj6Yn5EkABRJsPAALwiAH1WHgxtDbm5sDtWADdHiGSiBd8hSSyVCDkiAHRIrVMxnXKTzVjSdLyVyyeSoaQ2AwGIGLZaYWFuTjyAjSOSzeYAaxA3G4RpkADYI254%2BkSm5uJxoyppNx7YGndJ5EIQDJSAHHfM4LAYIgwU4Ynh2GQKBA0NXa31gCVolRawQIvmIKFs6RQgEagBPaR%2B0hNpxWAgAeVorDHjtIWC56nYA/wJwqADdMPnl5hxOVSas5OR6C0B7LQsRR3YsOP/cQ8E4n/N%2BIwWBueHw6ARhDESRlyUaJVHUFA3T0FQ8FCfNIHmVAYjaWgDwAWmBfY0S0PQDB4HY0IAdTYVUiKPAg7wImJMHQNQzGQNCImIEghDzFpyhQyxrGGVxoh8boCiKZQ4gSFCeOE7IUIE3pimaVpKnGcTSnYip2nGaTplksZOiUgZOg0oTOHmIRPRWLhrVtLNl2dKRxA8aM0NjHZgGQZAdhKI1OB2CBcEIEgfWiHY7GbOsAv%2BV1cL0f1s2DUgwzcdIjXjEp0nSABON44TeDxOHSXgbSkTNSDfdI3CNdKZE4NLtFjCMPHjNMHXPGy8wLIsYtIMtK3BGJSXISgmxrOtlBovzZM/Jg2A4X9P0AiQBwAdzvGJ33TKQ7VIJqcykWdSV6iFUCoHY7IcpyXLcjyvIgYKhoiMLopLeYEFOLBIj%2BNairfbhoyNbgZDSjwZDeBLUtTWNNoHFqjDa4sg1DEBtDeX7tBkUrUbcWM3DS7g3jWtwrOa3N2pLTqKy6iAkEGlt6wG1AQr6LY1GAKUKIcWgQz4Lse0oftlyHWhRyfSc6eneh50XTdMDXYAN2XLcOLwPcD3PI8T27AcOSvZcbzvYgRwfVYJwo19Vom79pt4WaRHmkCEZUJnIMiwwb3g96kJQ9DMLcbCoN0fCiJIgjCPIyi0Oo2j6DwBimJYtj5IsCAfF0/jJkEmYslEpJdJEnJaAM9OylU2gOiGewGmUQuUJLiZ8hkivFLLtJSnU1O66MhYljM9uCo2rbSBsk7HO4HZGfUbzWfZ/4fPwIhiAC0ggrp265/WbRwt9h64dIZ7mFeyh4fjI0UbeOrsvSN5Muyj75BKsrtCx6q0uxk/o1RtLMj7qH80LWGrVJ%2BAKYgB6n1BsVNhraG8DPEgygzZTS4Jbf8c1gLniWswFaUg/QWXWgTbau0CD7R2IdY69kh4j3AsAcexA2YhinjdamPo16bytE9F6fR3oFU%2BuGH6bxX5AxkKjbQpVsaowhtZIm39iZbzDNoDw5VcoyAxiUbQ3AaoYzxjg/uRNf6xQKtoDRUNtHzD3MQBIFhuBAA%3D%3D%3D) on both compilers.

Meanwhile, your original code behaves the same on GCC and Clang when [compiling for C++17](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRDbSV9ABk8tTADlnACNMYi4AZlIAB1QhQnNaO0cXN2jY%2BLofP0CnELDOSONMUwSGAmZiAiTnV3cikroyioIsgODQiKNyyuqUuu6W3zbcjoKASiNUB2JkDikdcN9kRywAak1wm3MhAmJMZicN7E0ZAEET053iB1NV87PNAHZ9M9W3u4gx9efVnfQQFBTAjrTYbGzrbTaU6fCHaDa6b4AEQu71WAD9oV8ngi/gC0A5gWCwbCMTCdHDwginsiHo9kZSLhdfMCnMxfJ9Gc8Ue9mATUKtWCDEb8CP8QL54mw8AAvUIAfVYeB2YPO4WOz0x1Ph3LeuMBBJBNmJ5IAdLDtbTEVIJqxpABWeSuWTyVDSI16Ay/KYzTAQ8KceQEaRyMYTADWIG43BNMgAbFHwom7ZwCtxOLGVNJuI7gy7pPIhCAZKQg86JnBYDBEICnFE8OwyBQIGha/WOsAU5w%2BPWCKFCxAgrnSEFfBUAJ7SAOkFtOKwEADytFYE%2BdpCwrPU7CH%2BD2JQAbphC6vMOJigS5nJyPRMLbV4qgsRx3YsJPA8Q8E5XxN%2BIwWFueHwdAEMIYiSKuShdqo6goAYBgqHgQSFpAEyoFEZh0EeAC0fwbIiWgenonCPKsmEAOpsIKZEnrszAkVEmDoGoZjIJhoTECQQgFjexToa4ECeL0rhdp4rQ5HkygxHEvGCRJ6S8aJ7T5EY3ENLQTQ9PYNTKPUvHqYM2SKdpAwyV2OzNApIz5BMQjerMXA2vaOarq6UjiAAHLGmHxqswDIMgqwpianCrBAuCECQfpdqsditg2kVfO6%2Bh6IGuahqQEbhHaJqJimdp2gAnI8kKPG5nB2rwt7ZqQn52uEJoFTInD5do8ZRm5iYZk6l4uQWRYlqlpAVtWQJRAS5CUC2dYNsoDHhUpP5MGwHAAT%2BIESEOADuj5RF%2BmZSA6pBdXmUjzgSo3AqgVCrO5nneb5/mBcFEAxVNoTxSlZYTAg%2BxYGEnx7VVn7cLGJrcDI%2BVuTIjyZXl6bxodQ49UYfWliG4ZuI8oPaDItU4%2BE8bhPl3CPHt4ROd1%2Bb9WWg1VkNEBIJNbaNhNqCxR0yxqMAcq7A4tBht2rC9sQ/aDquI60OOr7Tqzs70Iuy7bpgG7AFuq47jxeAHkel4nmevZDsyN5Dvej7EGOz5zFOuwfrtC1/stvCrSI63gakUEaLBejwYh8AoWhCRYTh4R4Z7uhESR5GsJRpHUY%2BdEMUxeAsWxHFcSYvGWNYJkeNYFniV2kkZIkmkpAXckJHnozKenpTGSXQnVxrjQDJXSlmRpyQN%2B3%2BnDPn1m2ctDn7eTx03V53CrBz6ghTzfNfKF%2BBEMQkWkNFrOvcvCzaAlocfWjpDfcwv2UOjiYmtjjxtSVdqPEVJUA/INV1dohPNflROX7GOP5XaCPOZThZiyo2tDTeA9MQAjTGk2Rm013CzSXsoO2S0uCOyAmtMCl4trMB2lIAMQ8DpHVIC5U6BBzqrEutdDy49J7uxntcOeIUXpMz9NvPe1ovo/Q6P9Sqj9Iwg0eF/KGMgcbaFqkTHGf8KZSF6kA1K6NtBuXqmVGQ%2BMUzaG4C1fGpMR5EMpsAtKt5tA6KRvoiYB5hYJEjEAA%3D%3D).

Comment: Upon reading this, it's hard to prohibit the thought to oneself that C++ initialization is an utter mess...

Comment: @Jodocus - [It's a known fact](https://i.imgur.com/3wlxtI0.gifv).

Answer (score 0):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary):

> Until the resolution of CWG issue 1696, a temporary is permitted to
> bound to a reference member in a constructor initializer list, and it
> persists only until the constructor exits, not as long as the object
> exists. Such initialization is ill-formed since CWG 1696, although
> many compilers still support it (a notable exception is clang).

Comment: i dont think this is relevant. The quote is about a temporary binding to a reference member in constructors initiaizer list.