# Ternary expression returning initializer list as the range expression in a ranged for loop yields unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, gcc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
using X = std::initializer_list<int>;
int main()
{
    for (int i: (true? X{7, 8, 2, 3, 9}: X{5, 6, 7}))
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

The expected output was

```
7 8 2 3 9
```

Instead, this code prints 5 uninitialized integers on the GCC compiler.

According to what I read about ranged for loops (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), the ternary operator is supposed to return an initializer list rvalue, and then that rvalue is supposed to be bound to the range expression which is a universal reference. If so, then why does the initializer list seem to get deleted somewhere along the way? What's going on with these uninitialized values?

Right now I see that using an `std::vector` instead

```
#include <vector>
using X = std::vector<int>;
```

the expected output is shown. Why is that? What goes wrong with `std::initializer_list` and doesn't go wrong with `std::vector`?

Comment: GCC 11.2 produces the desired result. https://godbolt.org/z/4chjr9K3c

Comment: [Works for me](https://ideone.com/PuhBg8) (gcc 8.3)

Comment: doesn't work with optimizations turned on (e.g. `-O2`), also address sanitizer complains about it: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1cshzbbbK) (gcc11.2)

Comment: Lifetime with `initializer_list` is tricky :-/ `initializer_list` is mostly just a view of a (temporary) array.

Comment: [lifetime of a std::initializer_list return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286450/lifetime-of-a-stdinitializer-list-return-value) seems to answer this.

Comment: gcc 11.2 also [work](https://godbolt.org/z/8Y3Tsas7Y)