How to initialize an intializer_list?
Some cpp class accept initializer_list as input, for example:
std::map<std::string, int> m{{"CPU", 10}, {"GPU", 15}, {"RAM", 20}};

or
std::map<std::string, int> m={{"CPU", 10}, {"GPU", 15}, {"RAM", 20}};

Is it possible, to define an initializer_list variable, then use it to call the constructor? i.e. something like:
auto il = {{"CPU", 10}, {"GPU", 15}, {"RAM", 20}};

std::map<std::string, int> m = il;


Note that initializer_list is a proxy object, it does not actually hold values. So using it as a universal storage to pass stuff around is not a good idea.

@user7860670 could you elaborate a bit more on why?

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286450

Yes. Example:
#include <initializer_list>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::string, int>> il = {
        {"CPU", 10}, {"GPU", 15}, {"RAM", 20}};

    std::map<std::string, int> m = il;
}


Yes, it's possible. You only need to specify the value type  of the initializer list explicitly.
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
  using map = std::map<std::string, int>;

  auto il = {map::value_type{"CPU", 10}, {"GPU", 15}, {"RAM", 20}};

  std::map<std::string, int> m = il;
}

or
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main() {
  auto il = {
      std::pair<const std::string, int>{"CPU", 10}, {"GPU", 15}, {"RAM", 20}};

  std::map<std::string, int> m = il;
}

